# the influence of the position to "return true/false" in a javascript nested if(){if(){}} function

Tags: javascript, return

Maybe a silly question, 
Is there a trick to correctly and easily place more than one return true/false in a nested if(){if(){if(){}}} statement?

**Just an example:**

**One array:** 
collection=[{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 },{"a":1,"b":1,"c":2}];

**One object:** 
source= { "a": 1, "c": 2 };

**Question:**
use **Array.filter(conditionFunc)** to match element from **source** to **collection**:
display those element with the same property and the same value from collection array.
I have some code below but my question is:

1 **Why** I should return true here?

2 If there is a if(){if(){}}, where should I **correctly return true**?

the answer should return [{ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 },{"a":1,"b":1,"c":2}]

**Wrong code below:**
Why the position to place "return true" after the first "return false" is wrong?

```
    var key=Object.keys(source);

    collection.filter(matchFun);

    function matchFun(item) {
        for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
            if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key[i]) || !source[[key[i]]] == item[key[i]]) {
                return false;
            }return true;  //this is wrong, but I don't know why?

        } 

    }
```

This is right code, but if there are more if(){} nested inside another if(){} I will get tripped where to "return true" the second time in different cases.Great thanks for anyone who can explain the mechanism to me

```
    key=Object.keys(source);

    collection.filter(matchFun);

    function matchFun(item) {
        for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
            if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key[i]) || !source[[key[i]]] == item[key[i]]) {
                return false;
            }

        } return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` causes the function to, well, return, which means the loop stops.  The first case is wrong because you don't know to return `false` until after the loop has terminated w/o returning `true`.